# Azure as a proxy for application

Tags: azure, dynamics-nav, dynamics-nav-2013

We need to develop integration between ERP (Dynamics Nav) and cloud-based telephony provider.

The provider needs to have an endpoint published and accessible from internet but for security reasons it is not possible for us to allow inbound connections to our network. I think it should be possible to solve this by hosting small application in Azure which will serve as endpoint for telephony provider and to which ERP will connect as outbound persistent connection. The app will just forward requests to ERP.

Since I'm new to Azure the question is what of azure capabilities I could use to solve the task aside from hosting actual VM with application there?

Answer (score 1):

I've just implemented the same using Azure Service Bus.
The VOIP system is putting a small JSON with call details after the end of the call and I'll get the messages from the Service Bus Queue from NAV.

The code is not complicated at all the whole solution is simple and cheap!

Let me know if you want to know more (= you need the code).

Cheers!

Comment: Hi Mak Sim, sorry for the delay, here you are : https://pastebin.com/UpA0gJww Expires is 2 weeks

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD has the concept of an "application proxy" that will open internal applications up using a connector that runs on prem. This doesn't require inbound ports and is protected by Azure AD authentication.

It's intended more as a user-facing way to get access to Legacy applications, although I don't see why it couldn't be used for integration as well.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/application-proxy-publish-azure-portal

Otherwise, you could link an Azure Site to Site VPN up and use a service like API gateway to manage connections though this is more complicated.